# SQL Update with Select does not update all correct columns

Tags: sql

I need to update a column of a table with values from another record in the same table.

My table looks something like this:

```
File Number       Suffix         Tax
--------------------------------------
   11997            N            504
   11997            V              0
   23761            N            103
   23761            C              0
   23761            V              0
```

I need to update any record with a 0 Tax value with the Tax value from the corresponding 'N' record.

In other words, the resulting table should look like this:

```
File Number       Suffix         Tax
--------------------------------------
   11997            N            504
   11997            V            504
   23761            N            103
   23761            C            103
   23761            V            103
```

This is the SQL I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #NRecord
(
    FileNum int, 
    Suffix Varchar(3), 
    Tax smallint
)

INSERT INTO #NRecord
    SELECT FileNum, Suffix, Tax
    FROM DatabaseTable
    WHERE Suffix = 'N' AND Tax > 0

UPDATE d  
SET d.Tax = #NRecord.Tax
FROM DatabaseTable d
INNER JOIN #NRecord ON (d.FileNum = #NRecord.FileNum)

DROP TABLE #NRecord
```

But it does not update the way I had hoped.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you didn't have in table d any columns that fit the bill aka haave the same filename with N and tax > 0

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above UPDATE FROM is product specific.)

Comment: It is SQL server, isn't it. Temp table creation is specific to SQL server.

Comment: it is very unclear what it means that *does not update the way I had hoped.* what does that mean exactly, also it would helpo if you add some sample data, so that we can see what happens and what you expected

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to create a temp table for this, you can update with a join:

```
update T
set Tax=S.Tax
from MyTbl T
     inner join
     MyTbl S
     on T.[File Number]=S.[File Number]
     and T.Tax=0 and T.Suffix<>'N'
     and S.Tax<>0 and S.Suffix='N'
```

If your database is not SqlServer the syntax may vary.

or this:

```
update MyTbl
set Tax=(select S.Tax 
        from MyTbl S 
        where MyTbl.[File Number]=S.[File Number]
         and S.Tax<>0 and S.Suffix='N'
     )
where Tax=0 and Suffix<>'N'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select FileNum, Suffix, Tax
  into #NRecord
  from DatabaseTable
where Suffix='N' and Tax>0;


UPDATE  d  SET   d.Tax = #NRecord.Tax
FROM DatabaseTable d
INNER JOIN #NRecord
ON (d.FileNum = #NRecord.FileNum);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eUwYTi-N)

EDIT: Simplier:

```
UPDATE databaseTable SET   Tax = #NRecord.Tax
FROM #NRecord
where (databaseTable.FileNum = #NRecord.FileNum);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/R7VQC4lT)